# Averaging Count For Unique Dates Separately

Tags: mysql, date, count, average

I am trying to find out an average number of times a user enters the office. I have a similar scenerio to the one below for unique users that come to office. My database has data for everytime a user comes to an office.

Please note: Everyone has different names, since I'm not using their name but some sort of ID.

```
Date         Person   Action
01-01-2014   John     Enter
01-01-2014   lilly    Enter
01-01-2014   lilly    Enter
01-01-2014   bill     Enter
01-02-2014   bill     Enter
01-02-2014   lilly    Enter
01-02-2014   bill     Enter
01-02-2014   John     Enter
01-02-2014   John     Enter
```

I can do a query to give me average by grouping users together and running an avg on the count, but it only works if I specify a date in the query. And I'm trying to make a query that would run the average for each date separately and give me an average for each date.

```
SELECT AVG(sub.count1)
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1, Date AS date1, user  FROM table1 WHERE         
date='01-01-2014' GROUP BY user
) AS sub
```

What I want in result

```
Date         Avgcount
01-01-2014   1.33
01-02-2014   1.667
```

thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want the average number of entries per person, per day... yes? In other words the total number of entries divided by the total number of people making those entries, right?

= # entries / # people making those entries

Yes?

If so, the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)/COUNT(DISTINCT person) 
FROM table1
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC;
```

The count(*) will show me the number of entries per day. If your table contains anything other than "Entry" actions, you'll need to add a where clause that says WHERE action = "Enter." But otherwise, we just take the total number of entries, divide by the distinct number of people making those entries, summarize it by the date, and order it in ASC order.

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for. Didn't expect it to be this simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, at least is the result that you want:

```sql
SELECT date1, AVG(sub.count1)
FROM (
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count1, Date AS date1, user  FROM table1
GROUP BY date1, user
) AS sub
GROUP BY date1
```

Comment: I don't think this result is any different from simply counting the number of entries and dividing by the number of unique people.... and the later avoids the subquery. Can you think of a counterexample in which the average of the averages of each user's daily entries would be different from the total number of entries divided by unique people who made them?

Comment: Nope, evanv's answer is a better one because it's simpler.